# AngularJS While Add location parameter it should maintain previously inserted

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url

When i add parameter using $location in url as shown below it first removes added data but i want to keep that previous data...

**Example with code**

Main url:
*http://localhost/angular_laravel/angjs/#/bag_list*

when i do this,

```
$location.path('/bag_list').search({category: cat_search});
```

it simply changes url to this,

http://localhost/angular_laravel/angjs/#/bag_list?category=1

now when next function doing something like this,

```
$location.path('/bag_list').search({model: model_search});
```

and then url changes to this,

http://localhost/angular_laravel/angjs/#/bag_list?model=1

but i want to keep both like this,

***I WANT LIKE THIS:***
http://localhost/angular_laravel/angjs/#/bag_list?model=1&category=1

My problem is that it deletes previous parameter but i want to keep that parameter,

any help...??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 options I believe.

If you are only setting a single value (as you are in the example) you can use the 2 argument form of the setter. eg.

```
$location.search('model', model_search);
```

If you need to set more than 1 (or your data is coming in as an object already) you can manually merge the values. eg.

```
$location.search(angular.extend({}, $location.search(), { model: model_search }));
```

Comment: `$location.search(angular.extend({}, $location.search(), { model: model_search }));` it make a huge sense about my programming life

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$location.path('/bag_list').search({category: cat_search, model: model_search});
```